# What does the word 性故か mean?

Tags: definitions

I found the word 性故か while reading. I tried to look at the dictionary but found nothing.

Here is the entire sentence:

> それとも逆らえぬ性故か

I don't really understand, please help!

Answer (score 5):

> I found the word 性故か while reading.

That is not a word; It is three words 「[性]{さが} + [故]{ゆえ} + か」

「性」 means "***one's nature***", "***one's disposition***", etc.  「[逆]{さか}らえぬ性」 thus means "***one's nature of not being able to defy others***", "***one's nature of not being able to swim against the current***", etc.  Without more context provided, it is impossible to know what is being talked about here.

「故」 means "***reason***".

「か」, of course, is a question marker.

Again, without further context, we could only say that 「それとも逆らえぬ性故か」 would mean along the lines of:

> "Or would it be because of (one's) nature of not being able to defy others?"

Answer (score 1):

性{さが} means attribute, character. 故{ゆえ} means cause, reason.

I think か in this phrase is used as telling oneself like 寝るとするか.

So 逆らえぬ性故{さがゆえ}か means the cause seems to be my attitude which I can't rebel.